# Detect car acceleration in Android app?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I want to incorporate some Accelerometer code into a Android application im working and want to see if this is possible. Basically what I need is for the code to detect car acceleration motion. I am not wanting to determine speed with the code but just distinguish if the phone is in a car and has accelerated motion (Hence the car is moving for the first time). I have gone through many different accelerometer applications to see if this motion produces a viable profile to go off of and it appears it does. Just looking for something that popups a "Hello World" dialog when it detects your in the car and its moving for the first time down the street. Any help would be appreciated and a simple yes or no its possible would work. I would also be interested in compensating anyone that is capable of doing this as well. I need this done like yesterday so please let me know.

Thank You,

JTW

Comment: Make your title more specific. Is this possible could be anything.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to detect that you're moving in a *car*, as opposed to on foot, bike, train, roller skates, etc?

Comment: This smells like "I need to hire a genius programmer, are you interested in solving my domain-specific problem on the fly?" ...

Comment: Yes, let's get more people focusing on their smartphones while they're driving.

Comment: @Jeff ... On skates on a train? :)

Comment: @DOK, perhaps the app disables the phone when you're in the car? :)

Comment: Following your title and tags, I must admit that 'this' in java is possible.

Answer (score 7):

> Basically what I need is for the code
>   to detect car acceleration motion.

As others have noted, there is no such thing as "car acceleration". There is only acceleration. Acceleration, as a concept in physics, can come from everything from a car to the device being shaken.

So, for example, [here is some code](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Sensor/Shaker/) that detects a device being shaken.

So, the question then becomes: can you come up with an acceleration value that is definitively from a car in motion? I suspect the answer is no, for most cars. For example, [this site](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2001/MeredithBarricella.shtml) indicates that a 2008 Aston Martin demonstrates an acceleration of 6.5 meters/second^2. The force of gravity is greater (9.8 meters/second^2). My shake code will only register a shake at around 12 meters/second^2 -- less than that, and simple movements will be considered a shake.

As another answer suggests, you are probably better served using GPS.

If, on the other hand, you can supply me with a 2008 Aston Martin for testing, I'd be happy to run some accelerometer experiments... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If by moving the car, the device moves :P

http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2009/03/15/android-accelerometer/

But probably, it would be better to combine it with  GPS.

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43005/1954